# hi i am having a problem with npm commands what ever i try i am getting a commen error

Tags: angular

hi i am having a problem with npm commands what ever i try i am getting a commen error whatever i try ng serve i am getting an error

Cannot find module @angular-devkit/build-angular in client
so i tried to install @angular-devkit/build-angular then the bellow error appeared

npm ERR! file C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\package.json
    npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1415 while parsing near '...ependencies": {
    npm ERR! JSON.parse     //"@angular-builders...'
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
    npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-08T10_37_20_315Z-debug.log
```

and here is that logs file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'G:\\Node\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'G:\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--no-cache' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose npm-session f9ccfd416a935a47
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly install loadCurrentTree
7 silly install readLocalPackageData
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1522ms
10 verbose stack Error: Failed to parse json
10 verbose stack Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '//{
10 verbose stack //  "name": "ARC...'
10 verbose stack     at parseError (G:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:452:11)
10 verbose stack     at parseJson (G:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:104:26)
10 verbose stack     at G:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:51:5
10 verbose stack     at G:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
10 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp
12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
13 verbose argv "G:\\Node\\node.exe" "G:\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-cache"
14 verbose node v10.15.0
15 verbose npm  v6.4.1
16 error file C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\package.json
17 error code EJSONPARSE
18 error JSON.parse Failed to parse json
18 error JSON.parse Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '//{
18 error JSON.parse //  "name": "ARC...'
19 error JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
19 error JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

AND here is MY pakjage.json file

```
{
  "name": "ARCAngular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics-cli": "^0.13.5",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angularjs-datepicker": "^2.1.23",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-combine-loaders": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    //"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.0.0",
    //"@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.30",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

it is started with this

```
  //"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.0.0",
    //"@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.0.0",
```

i tried install them directly in package.json
only one command i can use is

```
npm install @angular/cli
(or)
npm Uninstall @angular/cli
```

i tried all the previous solutions no use for my problem

and

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' twice.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' twice.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
    at webpack (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:39:37)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToObservable.js:10:20
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:82:29)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:76:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\Mohnish Miri\source\repos\ARCAngular\ARCAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:209:16)`
```

Comment: nake same error bro "npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

" idhi run chesthe fix ayindhi

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines of the `//` commented packages:

```
//"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.0.0",
//"@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.0.0",
```

And use this if you need comments in `package.json`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/x----x----x

Final output would look like:

```
//"x----x----x": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack, ^7.0.0",
//"x----x----x": "@angular-builders/dev-server, ^7.0.0",
```

Then when you want to re-add these packages, you would convert them back into normal packages on the list. Until then, the package "`x----x----x`" essentially makes them comments.

Comment: As you can read from the output log, the issue is the double slashes. You can't put comments into `package.json` files like that. `10 verbose stack Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '//{`

Comment: Can you put this into a github repo?

Comment: If you could be so kind to select my answer, if it was helpful, that would be great. Thank you!